# How to write a template process with variable parameters in stateless service?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I'd like to write a template class that always performs a predefined routine. One method is abstract so that implementing classes can define the custom processing action on the object.

The classes must strictly be stateless. No parameters can be saved.

```
@Service
abstract class BaseService {
    void invoke(DataVO data) {
        prepare(data);
        Response rsp = process(data);
        validate(rsp);  
    }

    void prepare(DataVO data) {
        //general data preparation
    }

    void validate(Response rsp) {
        //general validation
    }

    //each implementation can provide custom processor
    abstract Response process(DataVO);
}
```

I want to use it like this:

//service that takes data from a socket

```
@Service
class MySocket {
    @Autowired
    private List<BaseService> services;

    public income(InputStream stream) {
        //convert stream to data objects, eg DataVO, CustomerVO based on the input

        //then find d
        action = getActionType(stream);
        for (BaseService service : services) {
            if (service.canHandle(action)) {
                service.invoke(dataVO);
                //sometime, based on the action, provide additional params like CustomerVO etc
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem: sometimes I want the implementation , lasses to take 2-3 parameters in `process()` method, like `process(DataVO, CustomerVO, int)`. That's of course impossible using the code above. But how could I rewrite this so that the template method is executed, and just in between the process method with variable arguments is executed?

Comment: In your example, where would DataVO, CustomerVO and the int come from?  Can you include an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: My goal is to chose one of the implementation classes based on a condition, and then invoke the service found. I provided an example how I'd like to use it

Comment: How about encapsulating the varying parts into a context object or applying the command design pattern? That'd give you a stable signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very simple and abstract solution. First, we define a `ServiceContext` class that serves as a base class for holding all the references used in the service implementations later (it's basically a DTO).

```
class ServiceContext {
    // ...
}
```

Services can extend this base class on demand so that they can define their own context subclasses:

```
class SpecificServiceContext extends ServiceContext {

    // This service only needs a DataVO object
    private DataVO data;

}
```

When a service is selected while client code is iterating through registered services, it can create a context object holding references of anything it needs. Note that `service.getContext()` here is only an example to illustrate how it would work.

```
@Service
class MySocket {

    // ...

    public income(InputStream stream) {

        // ...

        for (BaseService service : services) {
            if (service.canHandle(action)) {

                // Here, getContext() returns a subclass of ServiceContext 
                // that holds the service specific objects 
                // (in this example dataVO)
                ServiceContext context = service.getContext();

                service.invoke(context);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

BaseService does it's old job without knowing anything about the actual services or types.

```
@Service
abstract class BaseService {

    void invoke(ServiceContext context) {

        // ...
        Response rsp = process(context);
        // ...

    }

    abstract Response process(ServiceContext context);
}
```

And finally, `BaseService` subclasses can define arbitrary behaviour using our previously encapsulated context.

```
@Service
class SpecificService extends BaseService {

    Response process(ServiceContext context) {
        SpecificServiceContext specificContext = (SpecificServiceContext) context;

        // Here, we can do whatever we want. Wow. Much happy. 

    }
}
```

Comment: That's a really neat idea, and probably the solution to those kind of problems! Especially I like the fact that by extending the `ServiceDTO` it's possible that every implementation can decide itself which DTO to use (a more general or a specific one).

Comment: One could even go further and make the generic `BaseService<T extends ServiceContext>`, so that calls on implementation classes are typesafe.

Comment: Exactly. My solution is far from complete, you can enhance it in many ways in order to provide a stable and extensible API.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new definition of the method invoke

```
void invoke(DataVO data, CustomerVO customer, int i) {
    prepare(data);
    Response rsp = process(data, customer, i);
    validate(rsp);  
}
```

and with the method process who come along:

```
//each implementation can provide custom processor
abstract Response process(DataVO data, CustomerVO customer, int i);
```

Comment: Hm, that would force each implementation to define every new `process` method I define, even if the implementation has no use of the objects provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a [Data Transfer Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) that contains all the data a process may want.

```
class ServiceDTO{

    public DataV0 getDataV0(){
        ...
    }

    public CustomerV0 getCustomerV0(){
        ...
    }
    ...etc

}
```

Now your process method takes a single paramter of type `ServiceDTO`

```
abstract Response process(ServiceDTO);


public income(InputStream stream) {
    //convert stream to DTO based on the input
    ServiceDTO dto = ...

    //then find d
    action = getActionType(stream);
    for (BaseService service : services) {
        if (service.canHandle(action)) {
            service.invoke(dto);
        }
    }
}
```

The nice thing about this is the process method will never change.  If you ever need to add more things to process, you add methods to the new DTO class.  Old code won't break since it won't call the new methods and the method signatures stay intact.